# Crontab won't run Shell Script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

Im trying to run a shell script with cron every day at 2am

Cron: `0 2 * * * /home/pi/TTD/startTTD.sh`

File:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/pi/TTD
/bin/sleep 3
./TwoToneDetect71d
```

File location: `/home/pi/TTD`

`./TwoToneDetect71d` is an application

I've tried running it under `sudo crontab -e` and `crontab -e` with no luck

Comment: Which version of Pi OS are you running?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or RPi OS, which is not Ubuntu and is thus offtopic?

Answer (score 1):

Relative path, `./` in `./TwoToneDetect71d` is your error. Instead, specify the full pathname to that application.